# Average of ten numbers in serial communication -Arduino

Tags: count, arduino, average

I want to read every 10 numbers of the serial read and to get the average of those numbers in arduino. in serial communication with arduino i want to take every 10 numbers from the serial communication and to display the average of those 10 numbers in arduino. Can anyone tell me how to do that in arduino? Thank You.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

Comment: Have you tried something? There are lots of strategies, we need more info.